# Prestashop Quick search block hook

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

i have very strange problem with latest version of prestashop installed when i unhook quick search block from displayTOP then slider and products got disturbed on page then i have to disable Quick search block from modules after that it works fine.
actually i want to display Quick search block separately on top using header.tpl file with 
method 
    {include file=$tpl_dir./modules/blocksearch/blocksearch-top.tpl}
kindly help me to resolve this issue i'm customizing the default-bootstrap theme and using prestashop 1.6.0.9

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may create a custom hook and attache the module quick search block to this hook and in the tpl call your new hook where you want like ! {HOOK_YOURHOOK}

in your module :

```
public function hookDisplayQuickSearch($params)
    {
 $this->hookTop($params)
    }
```

in header.tpl add

```
{HOOK_DISPLAYQUICKSEARCH}
```

Notice : i didn't try the code

Comment: sorry i tried it but it simply didn't work i created function in blocksearch.php file and then i called it as you said in header.tpl but it display nothing

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that you need to hook the module in this new hook in : Module -> position > hook

Then you choose your module and the position(hook) > save, 

Or juste reinstalle to module so it'll be hooked

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point clearly can u give me an example so i can better understand that what you are trying to explain.